# SQL IF block code causing error even though it shouldn't execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server, ssms-2012

I have a case in which I have SQL code with an IF-ELSE block. The code in the IF portion should not be reached, but I still get an error when the SQL executes. In the code I first test for the linked server, and when that fails, `@reval` is set to 1 and the `ELSE` block should execute and avoid the code in the `IF` block that needs to query the linked server, but I get this error:

`Msg -1, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].`

I am running the query from within SSMS 2012.
Why does this error occur?

```
declare @clientCode VARCHAR(7)
set @clientCode = '8001299'
declare @year INT
set @year = 2013

DECLARE @retVal INT        
-- test connectivity with linked database server
BEGIN TRY
       EXEC @retVal = sys.sp_testlinkedserver N'ATLAS'  
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
       SET @retval = SIGN(@@ERROR)
END CATCH

IF @retval = 0 -- connection attempt successful 
BEGIN
```

--THE FOLLOWING INSERT SQL STATEMENT CAUSES THE ERROR

```
        SET @contIndex = (SELECT ContIndex FROM ATLAS.Engine_sp.dbo.tblEngagement WHERE ClientCode = @clientCode)          
END
ELSE -- could not connect 
BEGIN
       -- execute code to pull from linked server 
END
```

Comment: 90% of the posted code is irrelevant. Reduce it to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem. Read about [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Bohemian - you could have given your advice and not given a down-vote.

Comment: I downvoted because no effort was made to diagnose the problem. You basically pasted your whole code and the error and asked us to debug your code. That's not how this site works. My previous advice still stands. If you follow it, you'll probably solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @Bohemian - I know how this site works, I don't ask questions without doing prior research and I don't need anyone to debug my code. I just wanted some advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll still parse and bind everything before it executes it. It's failing to bind here.

You could use `sp_executesql` to execute that line, and it should only validate when `sp_executesql` is actually called.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize that. I modified the offending SQL to VARCHAR variables passed to the sp_executesql procedure and now it works.