# If statement not working properly in sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I want to run following query

```
IF COL_LENGTH('table_name','IsDeleted') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF COL_LENGTH('table_name','IsActive') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE table_name 
        SET IsActive = ~IsDeleted
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_RENAME 'table_name.IsDeleted', 'IsActive', 'COLUMN'

        UPDATE table_name
        SET IsActive = ~IsActive
    END

    ALTER TABLE table_name
    DROP CONSTRAINT DF_table_name_IsDeleted
    ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN IsDeleted
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     --IsDeleted column does not exist
END
```

In my table there is no column with name "IsDeleted", so it shouldn't enter in the first if statement. But somehow it enters the first if statement in gives me error message:

> Invalid column name 'IsDeleted'."

at line SET IsActive = ~IsDeleted

What is wrong in my query? Why control is not going in else part. Is there any syntax error?

IsActive and IsDeleted are of type BIT

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL IF block code causing error even though it shouldn't execute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323075/sql-if-block-code-causing-error-even-though-it-shouldnt-execute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because SQL Server parses and validates the statement regardless of the `IF` statements, meaning it parses and validates the whole batch. So when parsing the statement:

```
UPDATE table_name SET  IsActive = ~IsDeleted
```

it errors out saying:

> Invalid column name IsDeleted

See this example:

```
IF 1 = 1 BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #temp(col INT)
END
ELSE BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #temp(col INT)
END
```

It produces an error:

> There is already an object named '#temp' in the database.

The workaround is to use `Dynamic SQL`.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
IF COL_LENGTH('table_name','IsDeleted') IS NOT NULL BEGIN

    IF COL_LENGTH('table_name','IsActive') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'UPDATE table_name SET IsActive = ~IsDeleted'
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        EXEC sp_RENAME 'table_name.IsDeleted', 'IsActive', 'COLUMN'
        SET @sql = 'UPDATE table_name SET IsActive = ~IsActive'     
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    END
    ....
END
```