# T-SQL If Else condition on the same Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
IF len(Variable) > 1
BEGIN
   SELECT * INTO #TEMPTAB FROM multiple joins
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO #TEMPTAB FROM different multiple joins
END

SELECT * FROM #TEMPTAB more large number of multiple joins & where & groupby

 ERROR: There is already an object #TEMPTAB defined 
 -- Because of select * into in IF and ELSE both
```

I don't want to create a temp table prior cause it has a lot of columns to be defined.
Is there a way around it?

Comment: This might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336965/if-statement-not-working-properly-in-sql-server-query/28337162#28337162

Comment: Laziness has a price :) basically: no

Comment: Couldn't you just use `#temptab1` and `#temptab2` and move the select into the if else clause and have it execute on the corresponding table?

Comment: @jpw I will then have to replicate my code which is around 1K lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a fun problem for me that is... Well I figured out four ways to do it. One is with a view, one with a temp Table, one with a physical table, and one with a stored procedure and global temp table. Let me know if you have any questions.

### View

```
DECLARE @Variable VARCHAR(10) = 'aa';

IF LEN(@Variable) > 1
BEGIN
    EXEC('CREATE VIEW yourView AS SELECT ''Greater than 1'' col')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    EXEC('CREATE VIEW yourView AS SELECT ''Less than 1'' col')
END

SELECT *
FROM yourView;

DROP VIEW yourView;
```

### Temp Table

```
DECLARE @Variable VARCHAR(100) = 'aa',
        --Default value is 0
        @percent INT = 0;

--If the length > 1, then change percent to 100 as to return the whole table
IF LEN(@Variable) > 1
    SET @percent = 100;

--If the length <=1, then @percent stays 0 and you return 0 percent of the table
SELECT TOP(@percent) PERCENT 'Greater than 1' col INTO #TEMPTAB

--If you didn't populate the table with rows, then use this query to populate it
IF(@percent = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TEMPTAB
    SELECT 'Less than 1' col
END

/*your 1k lines of code here*/
SELECT *
FROM #TEMPTAB

--Cleanup
DROP TABLE #tempTab
```

### Physical Table

```
DECLARE @Variable VARCHAR(10) = 'A';

IF len(@Variable) > 1
BEGIN
   SELECT 'Greater than 1' col INTO TEMPTAB 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Less than 1' col INTO TEMPTAB2
END

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPTAB2') IS NOT NULL
    --SP_Rename doesn't work on temp tables so that's why it's an actual table
    EXEC SP_RENAME 'TEMPTAB2','TEMPTAB','Object'

SELECT *
FROM TEMPTAB

DROP TABLE TEMPTAB;
```

### Stored Procedure with Global Temp Table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('yourProcedure') IS NOT NULL
        DROP PROCEDURE yourProcedure;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE yourProcedure
AS
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TEMPTAB') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE ##tempTab;
    SELECT 'Greater than 1' col INTO ##TEMPTAB
GO

DECLARE @Variable VARCHAR(10) = 'aaa';

IF LEN(@Variable) > 1
    BEGIN
        EXEC yourProcedure; 
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Less than 1' col INTO ##TEMPTAB
    END

SELECT *
FROM ##TEMPTAB

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TEMPTAB') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE ##TEMPTab;
```

Comment: I guess there is no clean way to accomplish the task!

Comment: I will not be able to use your physical table or view solution, your temp table solution agains brings me to the same problem where I will have to specify all the columns for my table(which is a lot). Thanks for the solutions though!

Comment: Yeah there is no clean solution. BTW the temp table solution does NOT require you to define the columns, but the temp tables need to be compatible. You can use your select into, then get table definition by scripting it to a create table statement. Shouldn't be too much work.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you consider dynamic query with global temporary tables? This works for me:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = CASE WHEN 1 = 2
                                  THEN 'SELECT * INTO ##TEMPTAB FROM dbo.SomeTable1'
                                  ELSE 'SELECT * INTO ##TEMPTAB FROM dbo.SomeTable2'
                             END
EXEC (@sql) 

SELECT  * FROM ##TEMPTAB
DROP TABLE ##TEMPTAB
```

Answer (score -1):

The first time you ran this code it created the table #TEMPTAB. The next time you ran SQL Server is telling you the table already exists. You should precede your code with the following:

```
if object_ID('tempdb..#TEMPTAB','U') is not null
   drop table #TEMPTAB
```

This will drop (delete the table if it already exists) and the code that follows will always be able to recreate(or create) the table.

Comment: Actually this won't work as the problem relates to how SQL Server resolves object names when it parses the query.

Comment: Please look at the error statement happs encountered. If happs would copy their code to another window the first time it would run (or maybe produce another error). The second time it would run, in the same window, it would produce the error listed.

Comment: No, it won't work. One can think that it should but it won't. Try the code here and see for yourself: http://pastebin.com/2FdLwW0Q

Comment: I was wrong. SQL Server assumes after that the first part of the if will create the table and that the second part may be executed (the else) and the table will already be there.

Comment: Indeed. The parser isn't smart enough to realize that only one code path can be executed (as it can't evaluate the condition before runtime).